# Accessing class method for object from within another class, C++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am working through the google c++ course database project and have run into a quandary. I have two classes Composer and Database for creation of composer objects and a database object to store an array of composers in. These classes are defined in .h files to be included in the final .cpp file. In the meantime I am working through the testing for each class with a test.cpp file for each. My composer class appears to be working as intended, but my database class is not accessing the methods from the composer class when i create a composer object in my database. Any help is greatly appreciated. The files are as follows.

The composer class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int kDefaultRanking = 10;

class Composer {

 public:
  Composer(): first_name_(), last_name_(), composer_yob_(), composer_genre_(), 
            ranking_(kDefaultRanking), fact_(){}

  void set_first_name(string in_first_name){
    first_name_ = in_first_name;
}
  void set_last_name(string in_last_name){
    last_name_ = in_last_name;
}
string get_last_name(){
    return last_name_;
}
  void set_composer_yob(int in_composer_yob){
    composer_yob_ = in_composer_yob;
}
  void set_composer_genre(string in_composer_genre){
    composer_genre_ = in_composer_genre;
}   
  void set_ranking(int in_ranking){
    ranking_ = in_ranking;
}
  void set_fact(string in_fact){
    fact_ = in_fact;
}

  void Promote(int increment){
    ranking_ -= increment;
}
    void Demote(int decrement){
    ranking_ += decrement;
}
  void Display(){
    cout << "First Name: " << first_name_ << endl;
    cout << "Last Name: " << last_name_ << endl;
    cout << "Year of Birth: " << composer_yob_ << endl;
    cout << "Genre: " << composer_genre_ << endl;
    cout << "Fact: " << fact_ << endl;
    cout << "Ranking: " << ranking_ << endl;
}

 private:
  string first_name_;
  string last_name_;
  int composer_yob_; // year of birth
  string composer_genre_; // baroque, classical, romantic, etc.
  string fact_;
  int ranking_;
};
```

the composer test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Composer.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << endl << "Testing the Composer class." << endl << endl;

  Composer composer;

  composer.set_first_name("Ludwig van");
  composer.set_last_name("Beethoven");
  composer.set_composer_yob(1770);
  composer.set_composer_genre("Romantic");
  composer.set_fact("Beethoven was completely deaf during the latter part of
                    his life - he never heard a performance of his 9th symphony.");
  composer.Promote(2);
  composer.Demote(1);
  composer.Display();
}
```

the database class:

```
#include  <iostream>
#include "Composer.h"

const int kMaxComposers = 100;

class Database {
 public:
  Database(): composers_(), next_slot_(0){}

 Composer& AddComposer(string in_first_name, string in_last_name, 
                        string in_genre, int in_yob, string in_fact){
    Composer composer;
    composers_[next_slot_] = composer;
    composer.set_first_name(in_first_name);
    composer.set_last_name(in_last_name);
    composer.set_composer_genre(in_genre);
    composer.set_composer_yob(in_yob);
    composer.set_fact(in_fact);
    next_slot_++;
    }                                               
  Composer& GetComposer(string in_last_name){
    for(int i=0;i<kMaxComposers;i++){
      if (composers_[i].get_last_name() == in_last_name){
        composers_[i].Display();
      }
    }
  }
 void DisplayAll(){
    for(int i=0;i<kMaxComposers;i++){
      if(composers_[i].get_last_name().length() > 0){
        composers_[i].Display();
      }
    }
  };
 void DisplayByRank();

 private:
  Composer composers_[kMaxComposers];
  int next_slot_;
};
```

the database test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Database.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  Database myDB;

 Composer& comp1 = myDB.AddComposer("Ludwig van", "Beethoven", "Romantic", 1770, 
             "Beethoven was completely deaf during the latter part of his life - he never 
             heard a performance of his 9th symphony.");
  comp1.Promote(7);

  Composer& comp2 = myDB.AddComposer("Johann Sebastian", "Bach", "Baroque", 1685,
                "Bach had 20 children, several of whom became famous musicians as well.");
  comp2.Promote(5);

  Composer& comp3 = myDB.AddComposer("Wolfgang Amadeus", "Mozart", "Classical", 1756,
                "Mozart feared for his life during his last year - there is some evidence 
                that he was poisoned.");
  comp3.Promote(2);

  cout << endl << "all Composers: " << endl << endl;
  myDB.DisplayAll();
}
```

When compiling and running testdatabase.cpp I get the proper display output for the composer class, but when the test calls comp1.promote(#) nothing occurs and the ranking prints out as 10 for each composer.

Comment: Can you shrink your code?

Comment: The Database::AddComposer() and Database::GetComposer method are declared to return a Composer&, but there are no return statement in them. How was that able to compile? As you do not run the code shown, we cannot tell you where the error is.

Comment: If you follow StackOverflow's advice and create an MVCE to reproduce this, you will probably solve it and learn something in the process. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Fredereic. The testdatabase.cpp file compiles and runs without errors. The only issue appears to be with the ranking value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Composer& AddComposer(string in_first_name, string in_last_name, 
                        string in_genre, int in_yob, string in_fact){
    Composer composer;
    composers_[next_slot_] = composer;
```

Try

```
Composer& AddComposer(string in_first_name, string in_last_name, 
                        string in_genre, int in_yob, string in_fact){
    Composer &composer = composers_[next_slot_];
```

Why this works => this is C++, not C#, you did not referenced the composers[x], but instead copied the content of the (at the moment) empty Composer.

Comment: Andrei. This almost solves the problem. It does allow comp1, 2, etc to access the Composer class methods, but when DisplayAll() runs at the end of testdatabase.cpp the output for rankings is still incorrect. However, when adding in a comp1.display() call the result shows the correct value for ranking. Any thoughts? From what i can see it appears that the ranking value is being carried over from comp1 to comp2 and comp3 and thus 10 -7 -5 -2 ends up displaying -4 for the first composer entry when the display all call is made

Comment: At the end of AddComposer(), after next_slot_++; add a line return composer;. Also, loop in DisplayAll can be rewritten to for (int i = 0; i < next_slot;i++)

Answer (score 0):

Making a friend class could help.